# How to call url with basic authentication inside application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, windows-services

I need to create an application (ASP.NET or WinForms or Windows Service, not sure) that needs to make a call to a url including username and password for basic authentication and have the url return a csv file.  I then need to use the csv file in the application.  I don't know how to do this.  How do I call the url in my app.  There can be no user interaction, it needs to be completely automated in the returning of the csv file.

Comment: I know you say basic authentication, but does your app use Forms Authentication?

Comment: You should accept an answer or provide some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
webClient.DownloadFile("http://someurl/file.csv", "c:\\file.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the `System.Net.WebRequest` class. Here is a page showing general usage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

You can swap out the assignment of the `Credentials` property with your own `NetworkCredential` object to pass a custom user name and password.

I actually handle the class a little differently than the example. I ensure that every class that is `IDisposable` is initialized in a using statement to avoid accidentally leaving unclaimed resources. This is especially important if your service will receive frequent or rapid traffic.

**Edit:**

If you're interested in a CSV parsing library, there are many you can find from any search. You might like the code from [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx). This library is flexible enough to handle properly-escaped multi-line fields.

Good luck!